# Italian equivalent to French St. Tropez or Spanish Marbella?

Tags: italy, destinations, beaches

You got these rich people orientated tourist beach towns like Marbella in Spain and St. Tropez in France.

My question is, which town/city is the Italian equivalent of Marbella or St. Tropez?

I mean, some rich location on the coast with a lot of millionaires and rich tourists.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As shard said there are several locations you can compare with St. Tropez. Let me add some to the list he already gave (in no particular order).

- [Porto Cervo (Sardegna)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porto_Cervo)
- Porto Rotondo (Sardegna)
- [Capri (Campania)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capri)
- [Amalfi (Campania)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amalfi)
- [Positano (Campania)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positano)
- [Portofino (Liguria)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portofino)
- [Taormina (Sicilia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taormina)
- [Panarea (Sicilia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panarea)

I would add some towns near Lago di Garda, like Gardone or near Lago di Como (where George Clooney has a villa) like Cernobbio and Bellagio.

Answer (score 8):

There are several locations compliant to the description you provided. For example in Liguria there is Portofino, in Toscana Forte dei Marmi, but maybe the most famous location on the coast with a lot of millionares and rich tourists is in the north-eastern part of Sardinia: the ["Costa Smeralda"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Costa_Smeralda).

Comment: Yep, can definitely confirm the Sardinia part.